# Running JSS-CLI to create app I'm getting "JSS CLI is running in global mode because it was not installed in the local node_modules folder" messaging

Tags: jss

I'm running **Windows 10**, **node v14.5.0** and **JSS v13.2.0** which is the latest at this time (I've literally just installed it). I'm trying to create an angular app with the JSS-CLI with the following:

```
jss create my-first-jss-app angular
```

When I run that in a newly created directory from a command prompt I get the following messaging and error:

```
JSS CLI is running in global mode because it was not installed in the local node_modules folder.
Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

I'm not sure if the error is related to the messaging about running in global mode so not sure if I have two issues or if the issues are even related.

Has anyone had this problem or know how to fix it?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things I found to fix the self signed certificate in certificate chain error.

```
set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
```

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

Also if you are behind a web proxy you can use the --proxy attribute so the jss cli can download the template from the sitecore git repo.

```
jss create my-first-jss-app angular --proxy <proxy url here>
```

Comment: I tried "npm config set strict-ssl false" but it didn't make any difference, I still get the same messaging and error.

Comment: And NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED is set to 0?

You can check this in a command prompt by running echo %NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED% and it should come back with 0.

Comment: Yep, it comes back 0.  Can you tell me if the messaging about running in global mode is an issue at all?  I'm not sure if I have one or two issues, nor if they're separate or related to each other.

Comment: I don't think running in global mode is an issue, in fact it is suppose to run that way when creating a new project. That error seems to come up when other errors occur, in this case not being able to call github for the angular template.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to look into the proxy side of things. Glad to hear the global messaging is probably not an issue as that did nothing but confuse me further (which doesn't take much these days).

Answer (score 1):

Make Sure that you are in the correct directory, initially i faced the same issue then i realized that directory path is not proper
[image]

with above command there was no output later i modified the path to my jss project folder then it worked
[image]

[image]

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

try "npm install" in your new created App "my-first-jss-app".
Steps
--> Inside my-first-jss-app

1. npm install
2. jss start