Server Error: self-signed certificate During local setup of Sitecore Headless SXA with Next.js
Error
Server Error
Error: self-signed certificate
This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.

Hello team,
I'm a newcomer to Sitecore and have recently completed a local setup of Sitecore Headless SXA with Next.js. While my Sitecore instance is functioning correctly, I'm encountering an issue when I try accessing http://localhost:3000 using jss start:connected.

Specifically, I'm receiving a self-signed certificate error. Any assistance or guidance on resolving this would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Does this help? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/25773/running-jss-cli-to-create-app-im-getting-jss-cli-is-running-in-global-mode-bec. Have you tried hitting https://localhost:3000? Can you share your Next.js logs when this occurs? Does this help? https://sitecore.marcelgruber.ca/posts/nextjs-unable-verify-first-certificate

Is there any error in console log?

I encountered a similar issue while setting up Sitecore Headless SXA with Next.js locally.
To resolve this problem when launching the application in connected mode,
follow these steps:
First Go to your root directory, run the following command:
$env:NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0


Then, start the application in connected mode:
jss start:connected

By executing these commands in this order, you should be able to resolve the issue and access http://localhost:3000 successfully.
Hope this helps!!!

Thanks this is working. @Praveen

In order to solve this issue, you will need to the add the following entry inside the .env file in the jss application you are running locally.
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0

Once above changes are made, you can re-run the above command jss start:connected again.
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issues.
